# Logical translation of the verb " to be " in " the cat is a mammal ". ( Inclusion or membership?)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

- Standardly, the sentence " the cat is a mammal " would be translated as

> for all x , if x is a cat, then x is a mammal,

meaning that the set of cats is included in the set of mammals : $C\subseteq M$.

- There is another interpretation: the species " cat" is a mammals species. Under this alternative interpretation ( admitting that a " species" is some sort of set or collection), we would have : $ C \in M $*

with C = the set of cats and M* = the *set of species* of mammals.

- The distinction I'm referring to is analogous to the medieval distinction between personal supposition and simple supposition of a term. In " horses are animals" the term " horse" supposes personnaly while in " horse is a species" , the term supposes simply.
- What are the drawbacks of the second interpretation ( where " is" is interpreted as membership relation holding between a species and a set of species)? Why has the first interpretation become standard?

Comment: If you look at a particular creature, you may want to say "this is a mammal" and mean it is an element of the mammal set rather than it is an element of an element of the mammal set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two interpretations refer to two distinct terms. $M$ is the set of mammals, where each element of $M$ is an individual (a mammal); while $M^*$ is the set of species that are mammals, where each element of $M^*$ is a set (a species) of individuals (the mammals).

The meaning of the verb "to be" is an inclusion or a membership relation depending on whether the "predicate" you want to consider is $M$ or $M^*$.
In the former, $C$ is a *subset* of $M$, in the latter $C$ is an *element* of $M^*$.

---

In set theory, you can say that $C \subseteq M$ is equivalent to $C \in \mathcal{P}(M)$, for any sets $C$ and $M$, where $\mathcal{P}(M)$ is the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $M$ (the set of all subsets of $M$).

Here, you are doing something similar. Your $M^*$ is not $\mathcal{P}(M)$ but a subset of it ($M^*$ "lives in the same realm" as $\mathcal{P}(M)$, if you like this ontological way of thinking), more precisely $M^*$ is the set of subsets of $M$ that are species.

From a psychological standpoint, I find more natural to interpret the sentence "cats are mammals" as $C \subseteq M$ because it requires less mathematical structures than $C \in M^*$. Anyway, the two interpretations are equivalent, so no one is preferable to the other one from a logical point of view (as soon as you are entitled to use powersets).

---

In first-order logic, it is quite natural and standard to interpret sentences in a *domain of individuals* to which quantifiers refer, and then to gather together individuals by means of *predicates*. So, according to Fregeian tradition, the sentence "the cat is a mammal" is translated in first-order logic as

> for all $x$ , if $x$ is a cat, then $x$ is a mammal,

i.e., (for $C(x) =$ "$x$ is a cat", and $M(x) =$ "$x$ is a mammal")

> $\forall x (C(x) \to M(x))$

which corresponds exactly the set-theoretic definition of $C \subseteq M$.

If you prefer to interpret the sentence "the cat is a mammal" as $C \in M^*$ where $C$ and $M$ are first-class elements in the domain of discourse, then you should define a way to interpret sentences which would require more mathematical structures  and where it would be clumsier to talk about single individuals.
I guess the domain should have many sorts of elements with a hierarchical structure: individuals (as me, you, my cat Zoe) and classes of these individuals (cats, mammals, human beings). It is not impossible, but technically more elaborated and less intuitive. See for instance [order-sorted logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic#Order-sorted_logic).

Answer (score 1):

"For all x , if x is a cat, then x is a mammal" is:

> $\forall x (\text {Cat}(x) \to \text {Mammal}(x))$

and this is exactly the definition of [set inclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions):

> $\text{Cat } \subseteq \text { Mammal}.$

---

Regarding the multiple uses of "is" into natural language, we can identify three different "contexts" :

- "Plato is a philosopher"; this context is relative to an object (or individual) *belonging* to a set or class.

In symbols this is expressed with $\text {Plato} \in \text {Philospher}$, i.e. $\text {Philospher}(\text {Plato})$.

- "a man is a male"; this context is relative to a *concept* subsumed under a more general" one.

In symbols it is expressed with *inclusion* (your example above).

- "$2+2 \text { is } 4$"; this context is relative to *identity*, i.e. the relation between two names denoting the same object.

It is simply: $2+2 = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

To see the problem with your second approach, consider the sentence "The Siamese cat is a mammal." The first approach translates simply as $S\subseteq M$; but your second approach requires us to define a new set $Q$, the set of sub-species of mammals, before we can say $C\in Q$. You can see how cumbersome this might get.